# Negative synonym for ambitious

Tags: synonyms

The word `ambitious` can be used to describe both positive and the negative traits of someone's personality, depending on context. Is there some synonym that conveys purely the negative meaning of `ambitious`, ie. greed and eagerness to get success, even through unfair means?

Comment: "Negative" is one dimensional. _Ambition_ is multi-dimensional, and they can be negated together or separately. There just ***aren't*** "negative synonyms" for most words. If you mean someone is an asshole, say so; but _ambition_ already invites the inference of a fair amount of eagerness and lack of principles.

Comment: Does it have to be one word?

Comment: over-ambitious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machiavellian springs to mind. Machiavelli's [*The Prince*](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/p/the-prince/book-summary) "is an extended analysis of how to acquire and maintain political power." The "ideal" prince, according to Machiavelli (Niccolò, 1469-1527) is essentially an amoral and ambitious leader of men whose primary and motivating ambition is to acquire, maintain, and extend his power through an end-justifies-means modus operandi.

Offhand, I cannot think of a better "negative" synonym for *ambitious*.

Comment: Although it has a very political connotation +1

Answer (score 1):

> **Careerist**
>   (kəˈrɪərɪst)
>   n
>
> > 1. a person who values success in his career above all else and seeks to advance it by any possible means

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but things rarely are.

I think its use is more often negative, more so than "ambitious". It could fit better into a negative context.